# String was not recognized as valid DateTime c#

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Why this line won't work?

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("04:05:14:17:17:09", "DD:MM:YY:HH:MM:SS", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

Comment: Out of interest, is the format under your control? If it is, I strongly suggest that you move to something more sensible, such as yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.

Comment: @JonSkeet Not it is not, this I receive the file from a server and I need to process it.

Comment: And the server is code from a different company? Oh well :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This format is very much not what you're trying to do.

Try changing it to `dd:MM:yy:HH:mm:ss`:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("04:05:14:17:17:09", "dd:MM:yy:HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);
```

So, what have I changed:

1. `MM` refers to months, `mm` is for minutes
2. `ss` needs to be lowercase
3. `dd` needs to be lowercase
4. `yy` needs to be lowercase

And just for the record, I left `HH` uppercase because that means it's 24-hour, but lowercase would be 12 hour.

You might want to review the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN page, where all these are explained. It has some good examples that might help you.

Comment: Colons in format strings *don't* need to be escaped, except for in TimeSpan. A colon means "the culture-specific time separator" - but that's a colon in the invariant culture anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, good point. I'm so used to dealing with `TimeSpan`s. Thanks. I will take that part out.